# How to check for array values in another array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, graphql

My query filter

```
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        allItems: (_, { value }) => getAllLinks()
            .then(result => filter(result, val => val.custom_attributes
                .find(customVal =>
                    customVal.attribute_code === 'category_ids' && isEqual(customVal.value, value)
                )
                )),
    },
```

My schema

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Item  {
        id: ID!
        name: String
        price: Float
        custom_attributes: [CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES]
    }

    union CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES = CustomString | CustomArray 

   type CustomString {
    attribute_code: String
    value: String
  }

  type CustomArray {
    attribute_code: String
    value: [String]

  } 

  type Query {
    allItems(value : [String]): [Item]!

  }
`;
```

For now (as I think) my filter works as `AND` condition in mysql.
For example, I have 3 fields
First

```
{
 value: ["3", "5"]
}
```

Second

```
{
 value: ["3", "5", "7"]
}
```

Third

```
{
 value: ["3"]
}
```

And my variable in argument is `["3"]`
Because I'm using isEqual function it will return only third field. That is incorrect, because `["3"]` is in all three fields. Is there another function from lodash that can fix this little issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different solutions, depending on what you want to achieve.

For the simple case where the `value` array always contains 1 element, both options will work.

I'll use this argument to show the difference: `["3", "7"]`

### Option1: Field must contain any value

If you expect to get **all 3 fields** because at least one item in the array (`"3"` in this case) is found in the variable and in `customVal.value` then you should use [lodash's intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#intersection) and check if the result is not an empty array. Something like:

```
intersection(customVal.value, value).length > 0
```

This expression is true if **at least one** item is found both in `customVal.value` and in `value`.

### Option2: Field must contain all values

If with my example you expect to get **only the second field** because all items in the array must be found in the variable and in `customVal.value` then you should use [lodash's difference](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#difference) and check if the result is an empty array. Something like:

```
difference(value, customVal.value).length === 0
```

In this case **the order of the arguments is important.**

This expression is true if **all** items that are in `value` are also found in `customVal.value`. Other values in `customVal.value` won't be returned by `difference` because we used `value` as the first argument.

(This option can also be achieved with `intersection` and comparing the result's length to the argument's array length)

Comment: Great thanks to You. Option 1 is that what I needed for now, but I'm sure that I'll use option 2 as well in near future.